# Getting Vue to update on object update

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

How can I get Vue js to update, when I update an object in Vuex?

Right now I have a mutation

```
EDIT_USER (state, user) {
    const record = state.users.find(element => element.id === user.id)
    let index = state.users.indexOf(record)
    state.users[index] = user
},
```

This works at the Object level, and in the console the state.users object is indeed updated.  But the view, doesnt automatically update.

If I splice first, and then push, it works as intended, and the view gets updated...but its ugly.

```
  EDIT_USER (state, user) {
     const record = state.users.find(element => element.id === user.id)
     state.users.splice(state.users.indexOf(record),1)s
     state.users.push(user)
  },
```

Its ugly because afterwards, its obviously at a new index, which makes it jump around in the table view after update. Not really the desired user experience here.

Id like a more, 'edit in place' style thing.

How can I get Vue to re-render, if I just update the object?  Either, locally, asynchronously, or from outside via websockets

I thought it was all supposed to be reactive, and automatic, which is why I chose a framework over Jquery.  But its starting to look like Jquery would've been the better choice, since I would've solved this hours ago already, and not be stuck for 5 hours, on such a dumb thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this section in the Vue documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

You need to use one of the following methods to get Vue to detect the array change.

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(example1.items, indexOfItem, newValue)

// Array.prototype.splice
example1.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

Comment: Even though the above answer is technically also correct, I chose this one, because I think its easier to reason about, and because you linked me to the exact relevant place in the Docs, which I definitely should've found before, but didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mutate state, return new one:

```javascript
EDIT_USER (state, user) {
    const index = state.users.findIndex(element => element.id === user.id)
    return state.users.map((element, i) => index === i ? user : element)
},
```

Above will create new array of users with user object taken from the old one, except for one that matches changed user id: in this case new `user` will be used.

Comment: I tried your method, and it worked.  I also tried the below method, and it also worked.  So technically both answers are correct.  Not sure what to do here, in terms of choosing the right answer lol   But on that note, I think the below method would be less 'expensive', because youre not creating a whole new array?  correct me if Im wrong